# How to change values in a list with respect to other list?

Tags: python, list, group-by

I have 2 lists:

```
Example 1:-

a=['AA','AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','BB','CC','CC','CC','CC','CC']
c = ['xyz', 'xyz', 'yy', 'xyz', 'zz', 'zy', 'zy', 'zy', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'lz', 'lz']

Example 2:-

a=['AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','BB','CC','CC','CC','CC','CC']
c = ['','','','','','xyz', 'xyz', 'yy', 'xyz', 'zz', 'zy', 'zy', 'zy', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'lz', 'lz']
```

So in these 2 lists,

For list a there are values repeating in groups of AA,BB and CC for those same repeated value's index I want to change values in list c.

In list c, I want to change values according to group AA's,BB's,CC's index in such a way that whichever value is repeating maximum number of times replaces other values in that group AA's,BB's,CC's index with the value which is being repeated maximum times.

```
Expected output of list c in example 1:- 

c=['xyz','xyz','xyz','xyz','zy','zy','zy','zy','ll','ll','ll','ll','ll']

Expected output of list c in example 2:-
c = ['','','','','','xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'zy', 'zy', 'zy', 'zy', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'll']
```

Because AA is repeated four times we checked first 4 values in list C and replaced all values which was being repeated the most. Same for BB and CC.

In example 2: I want to keep empty strings '' as it is and remaining logic should be same as example 1. Empty strings are repeated four times '' in input which should remain same in expected output and rest logic should be same for remaining non empty string values.

Comment: Well, create a list with the number of repetitions, like `[4, 4, ..., 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`. Combine the two lists, like `[(4, xyz), ...]`. Sort the list. Split the values again.

Comment: @deceze can you help with the code

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you stuck at something specific?

Comment: I have tried some stuff but it is no where close to what I want. I'm new to coding so would be great if you could help with this code.

Comment: I think you put the wrong input in `c` in your last edit.

Comment: Yes i had put the wrong mistakes by mistake but i corrected it. Expected c=['xyz','xyz','xyz','xyz','zy','zy','zy','zy','ll','ll','ll','ll','ll']. Sorry for putting wrong values

Comment: can u check the ques again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` with `zip` gives you slices of `c` based on consecutive equal values in `a`. With `collections.Counter` the most frequent value can be determined per group.

```py
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

a = ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC']
c = ['xyz', 'xyz', 'yy', 'xyz', 'zz', 'zy', 'zy', 'zy', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'lz', 'lz']

c_new = []

# zip a and c and group by a_i
for _, group in groupby(zip(a, c), key=lambda x:x[0]):

    # get the c values from the resulting [(a_i, c_i)] list
    c_elems = [x[1] for x in group]

    # count them, excluding ''
    counts = Counter(x for x in c_elems if x)
    
    # get the maximum
    c_max = max(counts, key=counts.get)
    
    # append '' or max_elem once for every element in the group
    for c_elem in c_elems:
        c_new.append(c_max if c_elem else c_elem)
```

Comment: can you check ques again, i made some mistake in list c values while editing

Comment: @edox741 I used the original values anyway.

Comment: I have a doubt which encounters 'nan' empty strings in my list c. For example : a=['AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','BB','CC','CC','CC','CC','CC']
c = ['','','','','','xyz', 'xyz', 'yy', 'xyz', 'zz', 'zy', 'zy', 'zy', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'lz', 'lz']

In expected output I want to keep empty '' as it as and rest logic should be same for repeated values so expected output would be:



c = ['','','','','','xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'zy', 'zy', 'zy', 'zy', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'll']

Comment: can you help with this please?

Comment: Please add that as an additional example to your question, it's totally illegible as comment.

Comment: can you check, i added example 2

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

A very primitive and naïve, but easily illustrated solution:

```
>>> a=['AA','AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','BB','CC','CC','CC','CC','CC']
>>> c=['xyz','xyz','xyz','xyz','zy','zy','zy','zy','ll','ll','ll','ll','ll']

>>> counts = [a.count(i) for i in a]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

>>> combined = list(zip(c, counts))
[('xyz', 4), ('xyz', 4), ('xyz', 4), ('xyz', 4), ('zy', 4), ('zy', 4), ('zy', 4), ('zy', 4), ('ll', 5), ('ll', 5), ('ll', 5), ('ll', 5), ('ll', 5)]

>>> d = sorted(combined, key=lambda i: i[1])
[('xyz', 4), ('xyz', 4), ('xyz', 4), ('xyz', 4), ('zy', 4), ('zy', 4), ('zy', 4), ('zy', 4), ('ll', 5), ('ll', 5), ('ll', 5), ('ll', 5), ('ll', 5)]

>>> e = [i[0] for i in d]
['xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'zy', 'zy', 'zy', 'zy', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'll']
```

Comment: I had put the wrong values of  list c in question while editing. Can you check the ques again